# flask form post : cannot submit Chinese charactor, only English words works

Tags: forms, flask

I cannot submit Chinese words in the form.
English word is OK.

How can I set the utf-8 ? 
In the html or app.py? or html code?

Here is my page: http://shiqiu.pw/testpage

**PS:** I can submit Chinese word in my mac, no problem. But when I deploy my code to my server, Chinese word can not be submitted, it shows Internal Server Error

**PPS**：I send my post words to mysql, and then show mysql data in new page, perhaps there is something need to set with my mysql?

```
        #myapp.py code part
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            # Create a new recrod
            word = request.form.get('word')
            print('word')
            print(word)
            meaning = request.form.get('meaning')
            sql = 'INSERT INTO sqdict (word, meaning) VALUES (%s, %s)'
            cursor.execute(sql, (word, meaning))  # execute

        # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save your changes.
        connection.commit()

        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = 'SELECT * from sqdict'
            cursor.execute(sql)
            # sqlresult = cursor.fetchone()  # only show the first row
            sqlresult = cursor.fetchall()  # all rows
            print('sqlresult')
            print(sqlresult)
            allwords = sqlresult
```

**ERROR LOG BELOW**

```
word
å·¥ä½œ
ERROR:flask.app:Exception on /test [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1993, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_response.py", line 269, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 1119, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'InternalError' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2311, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1835, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1850, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2001, in make_response
    reraise(TypeError, new_error, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1993, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_response.py", line 269, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 1119, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'InternalError' object is not callable
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a InternalError.
```

My input Chinese charactor is showed as '**å·¥ä½œ**'
I don't know which is the Internalerror object. 
Full code is at [github](https://github.com/Shiqiu2019/wedict/blob/master/myapp.py),code maybe not the same, but not big difference.

I have tried request.form.getunicode('word').
Also, I tried `app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII' = False)`.
Or, set `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the html code.
BUT, no one works.

**I hope the form can support Chinese words as value.**

Comment: The first task is to get a useful error message out of your code-- Internal Server Error just means your code failed. That ASCII works means it's likely an encoding error-- but without knowing if it's the database causing it (it allows UTF8?) or the 'printing' is causing the error, who knows.  Log the exception and you'll narrow the problem down.

Comment: @Doobeh Thank you for your comment!  I added the error message now. It shows 'InternalError' object is not callable , I don't know where the problem is. What is the InternalError object ?  But it shows my chinese charactor is printed as 'å·¥ä½œ'.

Comment: When your code is encountering an error (the L46 on your github code exception) you `return e` which is returning the Exception (InternalError) to the client.  You can't do that-- you need to return text, or similar-- something Flask knows how to handle.  I'd recommend either logging that exception to a file that you can access (or a service like Sentry etc) or-- as a clunky, unrecommened hack-- `return e.format_exc()` which /should/ spit the exception out to the browser as text.

Comment: @Doobeh Yes it is the `return` that got the error. I have changed that to `traceback.print_exc`.  And then find the problem. That I forgot to set my mysql table to utf-8. Now it works. Thank you !